# How do I grab files through ftp with php?

Tags: php, ftp

I have a setup where should I plug the following direct into my browser:

```
ftp://username:p4ssw0rd@ip.ad.dr.ess/Archive/test.txt
```

Access to the file is granted.  However I can't seem to grab these files with php, via `file_get_contents("$above_url")` - I receive the following error:

> [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: FTP server reports 550 /Archive/test.txt: not a plain file.

Ultimately I want to be able to save files to this location too.  Is it obvious what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `file_get_contents()` and hoping that PHP will by default do everything right, I would suggest that you use the [FTP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) or the [CURL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead. They allow you much better control over all settings related to FTP access. Especially considering that you are planning to write to the FTP location as well, you are better off establishing a proper way of dealing with FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$c = curl_init("ftp://$username:$password@ftp.example.com/$remote");
// $local is the location to store file on local client
$fh = fopen($local, 'w') or die($php_errormsg); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

You pass the URL to use to curl_init( ). Because the URL begins with ftp://, cURL knows to use the FTP protocol. Instead of a separate call to log on to the remote server, you embed the username and password directly into the URL. Next, you set the location to store the file on your server. Now you open a file named $local for writing and pass the file handle to curl_setopt( ) as the value for CURLOPT_FILE. When cURL transfers the file, it automatically writes to the file handle. Once everything is configured, you call curl_exec( )to initiate the transaction and then curl_close( ) to close the connection.

(from java-samples.com)

Comment: Yes, I've been doing some tests with curl as (partly) suggested by the previous answer, and it looks promising.  One question, can I use something equally simple to save a file to the remote folder?

Comment: @thesunneversets what is remote folder?